# Phonegap Cordova plugins deleting on build

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm having issues building a phonegap project which is deleting the cordova plugins directory on build.

A colleague has started an existing Phonegap project on his machine, versioned controlled it (via git) and has successfully run a 'phonegap build', which builds fine. When run in xcode on his machine, it runs run in the emulator as expected.

On my machine, I installed xcode, phonegap, cordova. I imported the project via git and opened this in xcode. On the CLI I changed directory to the project root directory and ran 'phonegap build'.

At this point, the '../www/plugins' directory is deleted. The build reports successful, but running this in via xcode dies at this point. Running via xcode before my local compile works fine.

I've attached a copy of my changed tree (M=modified, D=deleted). I'm at complete loss to this having searched and not found this issue reported anywhere. I'd appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugins directory should not be located in www. It should be located at the project root. As mentioned in the Cordova Github readme: https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli

Your build system is probably removing everything under www when you build your project.

Comment: There should be a plugins folder in the www of the platforms in the platform folder, this should contain the JS-side of the plugins but not the src that will be build into the platform.